# Images to appear at BOTTOM of a DIV

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add two images (ul,li) at the end of a DIV. I use position ABSOLUTE, RELATIVE and left:0, bottom:0, and it does it, but it doesnt remain on the div.

The images appear in the "MainDiv", and not in "container".

#### The css:

```
#MainDiv{
  background:url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  width:100%;
  height:600px;

}

#container{
  width:980px;
  height:600px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  }

#list{
  width:260px;
  height:40px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
}

#list li{
  width:130px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid white;
}
```

#### The Html:

```
<div id="MainDiv">
  <div id="container">
    <ul id="list">
      <li id="image1">Example1</li>
      <li id="image2">Example2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i see no problem with your code, exept that #container will have no height at all , since content is out of the flow

Comment: Because of the absolute positioning of the `<li>` technically your div is 0px tall. Try setting a height to it.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I actually have a height in "container". Code is too long to copy paste here. "MainDiv" is width:100% and height:600px, and "container" is width:980px and height:600px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolutely positioned element is positioned with respect to the corresponding edges of it's parent... from the look of it your container doesn't have any height set...

Comment: Yes, the height is 600px, same for "container" and "MainDiv".

Answer (score 0):

When you add a height to container it does move your `<ul>` to the bottom of the div. In fact, it is always at the bottom of the div, but because the height of the div is 0 it doesn't look like it is at the bottom of it.

### http://jsfiddle.net/s5aE3/

```
#container{
  width:980px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Damn... I'm stupid sometimes... I added Relative Position to the "MainContainer" and not to "Container". Works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The list is correctly positioned at the bottom of the container div, but there is nothing that gives the container div any height. As the height of the container div becomes zero, the list is placed with the bottom where the container div is.

To put the list inside the container div, you need to give the container div a height. Either by specifying a height style, or putting something inside it that isn't absolutely positioned or floating.

#### Edit:

With your updated code that has a height for the container div, the list is placed at the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the vertical align to bottom.

```
<style>
            #MainDiv{
          background:url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat;
          background-size:cover;
        }

            #container{
          width:980px;
          margin:0 auto;
          position:relative;
        }

        #list{
            width:260px;
        height:40px;
        position:absolute;
            left:0;
            bottom:0;
        }

       #list li{
            width:130px;
        height:40px;
        border:1px solid white;
        vertical-align:bottom;
    }
</style>
```

---

```
        <body>
            <div id="MainDiv">

                <div id="container">
                   <ul id="list">
                      <li id="image1>Example1</li>
                      <li id="image2>Example2</li>
                   </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Yes, just tested it, and it's still the same. Thanks for the help though.